# Prime ideals of $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, principal-ideal-domains

I want prove that every prime ideal of $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ is of the form $(\overline{P(X)})$, where $P(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is irreducible. Any help?

Comment: The polynomial $\overline{P(X)}$ needs to be irreducible which implies $P(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, but the implication doesn't go the other way, e.g. $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ but reducible over $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ for $p \equiv 1\bmod 4$.

Comment: Thanks. Now I noticed that my question is trivial.

Comment: Just a note: Every polynomial in $\mathbb F_p[X]$ (irreducible or not) has an irreducible representative in $\mathbb Z[X]$. This simply follows by Eisenstein, since you can choose the coefficients module a prime $q \neq p$ as you wish.

Comment: Also note the map $\varphi : f(X) \mapsto \overline{f(X)}$ is a surjective ring morphism, and you can say the same only because of that.

Answer (score 2):

In fact **every** non-zero ideal (prime or not) in $\mathbb F_p[X]$ is of the form $(\overline{P(X)})$ where $P(X) \in \mathbb Z[X]$ is irreducible.

We are in a PID, hence any ideal is generated by one single polynomial and you can always choose an irreducible representative in $\mathbb Z[X]$, because you can change the coefficients by multiples of $p$ and thus you can choose the representative to be $q$-Eisenstein for a fixed prime number $q \neq p$.

Comment: Neat! I don't understand the downvote, because I think you also left a suitable amount of work for the OP. Random bird droppings.

Comment: Or maybe someone couldn't believe the statment due to its counter intuitive nature. At first, I just wanted to leave a comment. But when I saw that the only answer does not really adress the subtlety of the question, I decided to give another answer.

Comment: Well, there is the point that if $P(X)$ is **monic** and not irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ then $\overline{P(X)}$ can't be irreducible either. I still like the point of any polynomial having an irreducible lift.

Comment: Yes, this point is of course valid. If you take the 'natural' lifting of an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb F_p[X]$, it is irreducible over the integers. But if one messes up and artificially increases the degree while lifting, one might end up with a reducible lift. So I do not think that this question is exactly the same as asking that over a field the prime ideals of the polynomial ring are precisely the ideals generated by irreducibles.